# How to retrieve the email contacts of provider from the iPhone os?

Tags: iphone, contacts, gigya

I have integrated gigya in iPhone for log in purpose. It's working fine. Now I need to retrieve the email contacts of the log in user. How to do that in iPhone programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally got it by

```
[gsAPI sendRequest:@"socialize.getContacts" params:nil useHTTPS:YES delegate:self context:nil];

}

- (void) gsDidReceiveResponse:(NSString*)method response:(GSResponse*)response context:(id)context
{ 
NSString *resMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n errorCode=%d\n errorMessage=%@\n response.data=%@\n",   
                    response.errorCode, response.errorMessage, [response.data stringValue]];  
  NSLog(@"gsDidReceiveResponse:\nMethod=%@\nResponse=%@\n context=%@",method,resMsg,context);
}
```